# Prototypes and object properties. Why do they act differently?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

Why does the prototype differ from a normal object?

```
var obj={'length':4}

obj._length=obj.length

console.log(obj._length);   // 4
```

An array is an object and its prototype is too, so the same behavior should be seen...

```
var a=[0,1,2,3];


Array.prototype._length=Array.prototype.length;


console.log(a.length,a._length);    // 4,0
```

I am not going to use this in practice but, I do want to better understand what is going on here.

**Edit**: How would you see the same behavior?

Comment: There isn't really a difference. Your mistake in the second example is that you assume that `Array.prototype.length === a.length`, which is not the caee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first case, you are creating a new property called `_length` on the object and assigning the `length` property's value in it. So, changing one will not affect the other. You can confirm it like this

```
var obj={'length':4}
obj._length=obj.length
console.log(obj._length);
# 4
obj.length = 15;
console.log(obj._length);
# 4
```

In your second case, when you create an Array object, the `length` property will be set on the object itself, whereas, `_length` is in the prototype chain, not on the object itself.

```
console.log(a.hasOwnProperty("length"), a.hasOwnProperty("_length"));
# true false
```

Also, you have created a variable in the `Array`'s prototype with the name `_length`, with the default length `0` (`console.log(Array.prototype.length);`). So, all the subsequent arrays will have that property too.

```
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3];
Array.prototype._length = Array.prototype.length;
console.log([]._length);
# 0
```

So, we are talking about two different properties here. `length` is specific to all the `Array` objects, where as `_length` is common to all the Array objects.

You can confirm that like this

```
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3];
Array.prototype._length = Array.prototype.length;
console.log([1, 2, 3]._length);
# 0
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4]._length);
# 0
```

Since `_length` is not on themselves, when you try to access them, they look up the prototype chain to find one in `Array.prototype`. So, they both are printing 0.

If you want to get the `length` with the `_length` property, you can define it in the prototype, like this

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "_length", {
    get: function() {
        return this.length;
    },
    set: function(newValue) {
        this.length = newValue;
    }
});

console.log([]._length);
# 0
console.log([1, 2, 3]._length);
# 3
```